# Mollifiers which don't 'preserve' the norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

If $f \in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ then fixing a compact $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ the classical construction of mollifiers tells us we can find a sequence $\{\phi_{\epsilon}\} \subset C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R})$ such that  $f \star \phi_{\epsilon} \to f$ uniformly on $U$ and $$\|f \star \phi_{\epsilon}\|_{\infty} \le \|f\|_{\infty}.$$

However, is it possible to find a sequence of mollifiers $\phi_{\epsilon}$ giving us the same convergence  $f \star \phi_{\epsilon} \to f$ but
$$\|f \star \phi_{\epsilon}\|_{\infty} \ge \|f\|_{\infty}$$
instead?

Comment: It maybe depends on your definition of "mollifier". It seems that you can use $\varphi_\varepsilon := \phi_\varepsilon \|f\|_\infty / \|\phi_\varepsilon \star f\|_\infty$.